# How to add additional JButton to JPanel when specific JComboBox item is selected

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jcombobox

I have been facing this small issue regarding making my JCombobox as dynamic as it can be.
For an example, when a selected item in combobox is selected, it will dynamically change the number of buttons accordance to the number of days within the month and be added in the panel

The problem i am facing is that it is not automatically changing the display of the panel , but when i tried to see if the code runs in my console log. it runs smoothly . ive tried my best to find a solution but to no avail.

The main problem is within the actionListener, for e.g if February is selected ,  it will display 28 buttons, if January is selected, it will display 31 days etc etc but when i run the code, my system.out.println states it runs but my Gui shows no button .

[image]

```
private static JButton method_Btn(int i){
    JButton btn = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
    return btn;
}

public static void day(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton days = new JButton();
    JLabel days_label = new JLabel();


    //-- Top Panel
    String month[] = {"--Select Month--" , "January", "February"};
    JComboBox month_combo = new JComboBox(month);
    topPanel.add(month_combo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    //-- Center Panel
    centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    centerPanel.add(days_label);



    //------- Change when jcombo is selected
    month_combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(month_combo.getSelectedItem().equals("January")){
                for(int i = 0;i < 31;i++){
                    centerPanel.add(method_Btn(i));
                }
            }

            if(month_combo.getSelectedItem().equals("February")){
                for(int i = 0;i < 28;i++){
                    centerPanel.add(method_Btn(i));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(centerPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    day();

}
```

Addtional Note, 
Ive come to realised an additional problem i faced is that it will stack up the number of button created after selecting the month 2nd time. How i solve it is i added centerPanel.removeAll(); and centerPanel.repaint();

```
month_combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int count = 0;
            //---- gettind days of month selected in comboBox


                if (month_combo.getSelectedItem().equals("February")) {
                    centerPanel.removeAll();
                    centerPanel.repaint();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
                        centerPanel.add(method_Btn(i));
                        System.out.println("days in feb " + i);
                    }
                    centerPanel.revalidate();
                }



            if (month_combo.getSelectedItem().equals("March")) {

                centerPanel.removeAll();
                centerPanel.repaint();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
                    centerPanel.add(method_Btn(i));
                }
                centerPanel.revalidate();

            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this help anybody who is in need. :)

Comment: documentation of [`JPanel.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)): *This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be **validated** thereafter in order to display the added component.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `revalidate()` the component you have added like following:

```
centerPanel.revalidate();
```

You need to change the following code:

```
month_combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(month_combo.getSelectedItem().equals("January")){
            for(int i = 0;i < 31;i++){
                centerPanel.add(method_Btn(i));
            }
        }

        if(month_combo.getSelectedItem().equals("February")){
            for(int i = 0;i < 28;i++){
                centerPanel.add(method_Btn(i));
            }
        }

        centerPanel.revalidate(); // Need to add this for revalidation for the component
    }
});
```

Comment: i totally forget about revalidate(); . Thanks. but there was another problem, when i added revalidate. for an example, when i select february, it successfully add 28 buttons, but as soon i select march , it will add another 30 buttons on top of the 28buttons that was added first.

Comment: Yes, because you are always adding new buttons to your panel. You can check the component children count etc. Surely you need to add some logic to your code as well. But, I think your original post question is resolved right :)

Comment: yes, thank you. i will look into it by adding some logic in removing all the buttons if panel contains component else it will add new jbutton accordance to the number of days within the month

Comment: If this answer is solved your issue, please mark it as approved so everyone knows that is the solution ;)